# Правильное использование констант

Tags: php, ооп

Я совсем недавно начал работать с ООП, и для определенных целей мне нужно было сделать собственный класс, который, к слову, отлично работает.

```
class Testing
{
    const PATH_ACHIEVEMENT =__DIR__.'/images/';

    const FONT_REGULAR = __DIR__.'/fonts/Arial.ttf';
    const FONT_STATIC = __DIR__.'/fonts/TimesNewRoman.ttf';

    const PATH_CFG = __DIR__.'/cfg/';

    const CFG_RU = self::PATH_CFG.'russian.ini';
    const CFG_EN = self::PATH_CFG.'english.ini';
}
```

Но перейду к своей проблеме, дело в том, что я не знаю, разумно ли создавать подобные константы? Для меня это сомнительно даже по визуальной части. Может есть какие-то другие варианты, как это реализовать? Может это нормальная практика, но я буду благодарен за любую консультацию. Спасибо.

Comment: Лучше сделать метод configure(params) и отдельный класс который задает конфигурацию. В вашем случае нужно постоянно переписывать код.

Comment: @becouse, вы имеете ввиду [что-то подобное](https://ideone.com/PDtNzo)?

Comment: Нет. Я имею в виду, что у вас в классе есть конфигурационные параметры, которые образуют структуру. Вот и передавайте в класс структуру с значениями.

Comment: @becouse, не совсем понимаю как это должно выглядеть, можете дать пример в лоб?

Comment: Представьте ситуацию, когда вам нужны будут 2 объекта класса `Testing` но с разными путями, шрифтами и конфигурациями. Как вы их создадите? Никак, потому что пути жёстко зашиты в класс.

Comment: @ArchDemon, что же делать?

Comment: Вам ответ написали ниже. Конфигурацию объектов лучше выносить в конструктор или метод класса. я делаю так `public __construct(array $config) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример использования класса для хранения и установки параметров и другого для работы с ними.

```
class FOO {
    var $par1;
    var $par2;

    // методы:
     function getPar1() {
     echo $this->par1;
     }

     function setPar1($par1) {
     $this->par1 = $par1;
     }

     function getPar2() {
     echo $this->par2;
     }

     function setPar2($par2) {
     $this->par2 = $par2;
     }

    }

    class BAR {
    var $params;

     function getParams() {
     echo $this->params;
     }

     function setParams($params) {
     $this->params = $params;
     }

     function useParams() {
     echo $this->params->par1;
      другой код
     }


    }

    $params= new FOO;
    $params->setPar1("SOME DATA");
    $params->setPar2("ANOTHER DATA");

    $myobject= new BAR;
    $myobject->setParams($params);
```